# How do I return a Mono<List<Object>> into a HashMap?

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

I have a hashmap of <Integer, QueryObj> that I need to iterate over and call an external service with. The method signature of my external service is like:

```
private Mono<List<ReturnedObj>> fetchList(QueryObj query)
```

and I've been able to verify that it's working and returns a list of what I need. However, I'm unsure of what my next steps should be and what my response type in the parent method should be in order to maintain reactive practices. Basically, I want to transform the `Map<Integer, Query>` into `Map<Integer, Mono<List<ReturnedObj>>`. I am wondering if `Map<Integer, Mono<List<ReturnedObj>>` is even possible? Does it need to be `Mono<Map<K<V>>`?

Here is the current code snippet - it doesn't throw an error, but rather returns an empty result. I'm thinking the mix of imperative and reactive programming doesn't wait for the results of `fetchList()` to populate the response.

```
Map<Integer, QueryObj> queryMap = getQueries(); // setup
return queryMap.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            e -> e.getKey(), e -> {
                                try {
                                     return fetchList(e.getValue());
                                } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                return null;
                            }));
        }
```

Would greatly appreciate any help! I am fairly new to this.

Comment: `I am wondering if Map<Integer, Mono<List<ReturnedObj>>> is even possible?`. Sure, why not? What do you mean `empty`. Nothing will populate the results until you subscribe to each of the `Monos`. Are you sure you don't want to fetch the results of the `Monos` and return a `Map<Integer, List<ReturnedObj>>`? Check out `Mono::zip`.

Comment: @K.Nicholas is right. Depending on your need, you might want to reverse the logic, to return a `Flux<Tuple2<Integer, List<ReturnedObj>>`. That should make all the pipeline "cold", meaning that someone consuming the flux will trigger the queries. If, on the contrary, you really want a `Map<Integer, Mono<List<ReturnedObj>>` because you want to process queries eagerly, then cache them, you might want to look at `cache()` and `connect()` operators on Mono. If you're still struggling, add some more context to your question, then reply to me me in comment. Then I'll try to post a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the suggestions - I ended up finding a solution that works for me. I ended up making my whole flow reactive (as I should have done from the start) and changed the return type of my method to be Mono<Map<Integer, List>. I used a `Flux.fromIterable()` with `flatMap()` on the entrySet and collectMap to get the results together into a map.